# Unable to connect to wireless network connection after password change?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection

I have changed the network password for my wireless network connection.  After changing the password all my roommates are able to connect to the wireless network with new password.

One of my friends is not able to connect to it, and her system waits for the network to detect for a long time. It's an Windows XP system.  I am also using an XP system, but I am able to connect. We used trial and error to troubleshoot the system.

Note: She is able to connect to the other flat's wireless network, but not ours.

Answer (score 1):

very simple solution she just needs to update her wireless driver her wifi drivers might be out of date not accommodating the wireless router setting particularly if it's secured with wpa or wpa2. So that should correct this issue. So hardwire her machine and go to device manager in system (control panel ) look for wireless device and run update if windows doesn't have a signature update for it you might have to download it manually and update it that one. Best thing to do go through manafacture site and download it from there using their model number of the machine should be under support.

hope that helps.

cheers